# Interacting with a verified location? - Google Maps

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-maps

Ok so there are loads of **Businesses marked on Google Maps** these days.

But I cannot interact with these in any way.

This is the information I have:

> venue name: **Ministry of Sound**
>
> address: **103 Gaunt Street London, SE1 6DP**

Google's Geolocation ***only*** gives me

- **Coordinates** (lat, long)
- **Formatted Address**

---

---

**I want an application to access this page** -> [Ministry of Sound - Google Page](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/place?rlz=1C1DVCC_enGB349GB349&sourceid=chrome&um=1&ie=UTF-8&q=ministry+of+sound&fb=1&gl=uk&hq=ministry+of+sound&hnear=England,+London&cid=10261706798760627533&pcsi=10261706798760627533,1&ei=PFhaS5ycH5740wTmtKz5BA&sa=X&oi=local_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBAQnQIwAA)

I would like to:

- Add **reviews** (eg. sites like Qype, ViewLondon, Frommers do it!)
- Add **photos** and **videos**
- Add Other Content

Also I would like to:

- Link an address to the Business automatically if possible

> eg. if the business shares the same address

---

### Edit:

**SilentGhost** said ***"Google just indexes and aggregates information from the sites"***

If the only way to get reviews and information on the site is to get it indexed...

**how do I tell Google that what my site contains are:**

- **Photo** of the Venues
- **Reviews** of the Venue
- **Information** about the Venue?

---

Help would be very much appreciated. thanks! :)

Comment: a little less boldface wouldn't hurt (neither would a little less verbosity)

Answer (score 2):

In response to your edited question:

You should look at microformats like [hReview](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview), Google indexes and uses these in search results if not on the page you linked to. See: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html

Comment: Thanks Richard. This is a very useful reply! I'll comment more on it once I finish reading the articles.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a certain confusion here. The main reason that you cannot interact with this information and for the lack of API is because none of these things (reviews, photos, videos, other content) is actually owned by Google. Google just indexes and aggregates information from the sites like Qype, ViewLondon, etc. It is a catalogue of sorts to get an overview and explore certain aspects further.

Comment: if you are a business owner, you *can* interact with this information. http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21030 : *However, the basic information that you submit through the Local Business Center is the information that we trust the most. This means that it will appear instead of any basic information that we get from anywhere else.* and you *can* upload photos and videos: http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21037#photovideo

Comment: Thanks for the reply. :) I own a site which has reviews for these businesses!

Comment: Hey SilentGhost how do I tell Google that my site contains items like reviews, photos and so on?? If Google Indexes those site for reviews, how do I tell Google to do the same with my site? :)

Comment: @ax: but you cannot do this programmatically!

Comment: @RadiantHex: I suppose by hosting reviews and just getting indexed by google as normal.

Comment: @SilentGhost I am hosting reviews... but it is just like any other webpage. How do I tell Google that *this* <div/> or <li/> contains a review?

Comment: @SilentGhost also reviews seem to be quite elaborate, as in they have scores and "n out of m people found this review useful" features. Google indexing has no way of knowing if you don't let it know I guess.

Comment: @RadiantHex: well, voting itself is going on the Google site and you can vote if you're logged in. There is nothing particular you need to do to emphasise that you have reviews. I think google is smart enough to figure that out. I think it's more important to have a good google ranking, that is being unique and relevant to certain keyword searches. It would be hard to achieve in the case of big and popular competitors.

Comment: @SilentGhost: i didn't say so - i am just referring to your *the main reason [...] for the lack of [an] API is because none of these things (reviews, photos, videos, other content) is actually owned by Google.* if you upload photos, videos, other content to their site via the Local Business Center, it *is* kind of owned by them and could be exposed via API. at least that's what they do with other user contributed content (picasa, etc.)

Comment: You should look at microformats like hReview, Google indexes and uses these in search result if not on the page you linked to.
http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview
http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html

Comment: @Richard M: Thank you that was really helpful! Could you repost it among the answers?

Answer (score 1):

You probably would have to get in touch with Google to let them know about your site and get them to include your reviews in their maps. Have a look at [this](http://www.google.com/submityourcontent/index.html) and [this](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/request.py?contact_type=partner&hl=en) page which is specifically aimed at businesses who want to distribute their content through the Google apps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'll write up that form and send the details to Google. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Google product of local business entries you are referring to is called "Local Business Cent[[er](http://www.google.com/local/add/?gl=US)|[re](http://www.google.com/local/add/?gl=GB)]". As far as I know, there is no API to access and manipulate these entries *. You can, however, [add coupons, photos, videos, etc. via web interface](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=13416), even in [bulk](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21033). Note that [you *can not* add reviews](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21037#reviews) to your own listings.

If you only want to access the [Place Page](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/09/place-pages-for-google-maps-there-are.html), there are [various ways](http://osdir.com/ml/GoogleMapsAPI/2009-11/msg02192.html) (address, coordinates) to do so.

* The closest it gets is the [AdWords Location Extensions](http://adwordsapi.blogspot.com/2009/12/discover-v2009-location-extensions.html), which lets AdWords *pull addresses directly from your Local Business Center (LBC) account* (and put their map data into your ads).