# getting google map searched location review and information

Tags: google-maps

i am wondering if there is any way we can pull the reviews and information of a location/store/shop/building from google map info, check following url please.

http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=16753855001018446220
http://maps.google.com/places/us/california/san-francisco/24th-st/2884/-la-palma-mexicatessen

Comment: looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121780/interacting-with-a-verified-location-google-maps/2134215#2134215

Comment: Have you considered using something such as yelp to gather the results instead?

Comment: do you have any link for yelp with what i want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL of the info page pretty easily. Like TreeUK initially suggested, use the local search API, and upon its completion, you'll have access to `yourSearcher.results`. For each one, just grab `result.url` (or `yourSearcher.results[i].url` to be more precise) to get the info page.

If you want the direct link to the reviews page, modify the `result.url` a bit...

```
var baseUrl = 'http://www.google.com/maps/place?';
var cid = result.url.match(/cid=\d*/gi)[0];
var reviewsUrl = baseUrl + cid + '&view=feature&mcsrc=detailed_reviews';
```

...then do what you want with reviewsUrl.

If you want more reviews, add the `num` (and optionally the start) parameter to the query string:

```
var reviewsUrl = baseUrl + cid + '&view=feature&mcsrc=detailed_reviews&num=100&start=0';
```

So, really all you need is the cid. Once you have that, you can get at any of the other info.

Comment: i dont want to put link, i want to put data only.

Comment: Just scrape the data from that link.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use  [Google Maps Local Search APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GlocalSearch).

Or to use Something like ax said in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121780/interacting-with-a-verified-location-google-maps/2134215#2134215)

> if you are a business owner, you can
>   interact with this information.
>   [maps.google.com/support/bin/…](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?hl=en&page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21030) :
>   However, the basic information that
>   you submit through the Local Business
>   Center is the information that we
>   trust the most. This means that it
>   will appear instead of any basic
>   information that we get from anywhere
>   else. and you can upload photos and
>   videos: [maps.google.com/support/bin/…](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21037#photovideo)

note that you can not Add Review [check this for more info](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=21029&topic=21037#reviews)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to hit up the [Google Maps Local Search](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GlocalSearch) APIs.

Upon completion of a `google.search.LocalSearch()` search it delivers a collection of `GlocalResult` objects. This contains Local business results, but you don't have any further control over them. There doesn't seem to be an explicit Local Business API.

I couldn't find any mention of reviews or Business reviews, have you considered emailing / otherwise contacting some google contacts asking about this?

Comment: i dont know any email address to contact them, last time i went on there google group, that didnt let me make a post. if you have there address, do share, so i can contact them. thanks

Comment: True, they even say they don't respond to email.

Looks like you're bang out of luck on this one.

Comment: no, i have hopes, one way or other, there will be solution, if not, then have to make one.. but for now, ill wait with patince and see if anyone comes up with something. but thank you treeuk for trying :). apprecaite it

Comment: @basit. @TreeUK - google is for crap when it comes to issues via email even when you are paying big bucks.